# Problem in email validation when using express-validator

Tags: javascript, express-validator

I followed in the steps of a fullstack course. This problem is related to the express-validator dependency. I configured and pasted the code that was passed to me. And in the postman when sending in the sigup url, the following error message appeared:

```
{
         "error": "Email must contain @"
}
```

But that wasn’t supposed to happen, because I had inserted the @ in the email

```
{
"name": "dave",
"email": "dave@gmail.com",
"password": "rrrrrr9"
}
```

Here are the information and codes for my application:

Express-validator version: ^ 5.3.1

**app.js file:**

```
const expressValidator = require ('express-validator')

app.use (expressValidator ())
```

**validator/index.js file:**

```
exports.userSignupValidator = (req, res, next) => {
  req.check ('name', 'Name is required'). notEmpty ()
  req.check ('name', 'Email must be between 3 to 32 characters')
     .matches (/.+\@.+\..+/)
     .withMessage ('Email must contain @')
     .isLength ({
       min: 4,
       max: 32
     })
     req.check ('password', 'Password is required'). notEmpty ()
     req.check ('password')
     .isLength ({min: 6})
     .withMessage ('Password must contain at least 6 characters')
     .matches (/ \ d /)
     .withMessage ("Password must contain a number")
       const errors = req.validationErrors ()
       if (errors) {
         const firstError = errors.map (error => error.msg) [0]
         return res.status (400) .json ({error: firstError})
       }
       next ()
}
```

**routes/user.js file:**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const {userSignupValidator} = require('../validator')
router.post("/signup", userSignupValidator, signup)


module.exports = router
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't this `req.check ('name', 'Email must be between 3 to 32 characters')` be `req.check ('email', 'Email must be between 3 to 32 characters')`?

Comment: No problem. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: Yes! It does! Apparently I thought it had nothing to do with the problem, but it was exactly that little detail that was causing the error. Post this code of yours in the reply so I can upvote you

Comment: It's all right. Just give @Kalki222 that upvote. He got it right as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this :-

```
     [
    check("name", "Name is required").not().isEmpty(),
    check("email", "Please enter valid email").isEmail(),
    check(
      "password",
      "Please enter valid password with 6 or more characters"
    ).isLength({ min: 6 }),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
```